# Play a sound before selecting - Android Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a list of sounds (entries in an array) for notification that the user can select from app's preferences, however, the user only has the option to read the sound name but not to hear it before selecting.
How can i add this option in my code?

Comment: Why not present in a list view with buttons to tap that will play the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Will help you this options:

- [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)
- [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

I recommend SoundPool.